# What will happen if storage of local machine is smaller than dropbox storage

Tags: dropbox, cloud-storage

Let's assume I have a dropbox pro account which gives 1TB of storage & the storage is fully occupied with data.If my local machine storage is less than 1 TB, can anyone please explain me about the behavior of "my local dropbox folder"?

I know that all data cannot be downloaded to my desktop(local dropbox folder)due to lack of storage.I have following questions

1.What will happen if I access a file which is not there in local dropbox folder. Will it be downloaded?

2. Which files are stores locally out of all the files in cloud storage.
   Does dropbox consider about file access patterns?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Can't access a file which is not there in local dropbox folder.
2. No, Dropbox has an option called "selective sync" - user determines which folders should be in local out of all the folders. If your local storage is not sufficient it gives a message stating that.